# Rails 3 - check that object is valid with params before update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have very newbie question. How can i check that object of model is valid with new params BEFORE updating it?

I want transform that:

```
def update
  @obj = SomeModel.find( params[:id] )

  if @obj.update_attributes( params[:obj] )
    # That have been updated
  else
    # Ups, errors!
  end
end
```

To something like that:

```
def update
  @obj = SomeModel.find( params[:id] )

  if @obj.valid_with_new_params( params[:obj] )
    @obj.update_attributes( params[:obj] )
  else
    # Ups, errors!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To update the attributes without saving them, you can use

```
@obj.assign_attributes( params[:obj] )
```

Then to check if the object is valid, you can call

```
@obj.valid?
```

If the object is *not* valid, you can see the errors (only after calling `.valid?`) by calling

```
@obj.errors
```

If the object *is* valid, you can save it by calling

```
@obj.save
```

However, all of this *usually* isn't necessary. If the object isn't valid, then ActiveRecord won't save the object to the database, so all of the attribute changes are forgotten when you leave the controller action.

Also, since an invalid record won't be saved to the database, you can always just call Object.find() again to get the original object back.

Comment: After @obj.attributes( params[:obj] ), call @obj.save.

Comment: The `attributes()` method as shown in this answer at the time of this writing is deprecated. Instead use `assign_attributes(new_attributes)` or the alias `attributes=(new_attributes)`. Thus the first line in this answer should be `@obj.assign_attributes( params[:obj] )`. See [ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html)

Comment: Re: `assign_attributes(new_attributes)` -- note that *the only attributes set are those named by keys in the params hash*. So if you have an existing object, you can add/merge just a subset of attributes.

Comment: For the curious, this is straight out of the [`update(attributes)` playbook](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) (which by the way is aliased as `update_attributes(attributes)`) -- [View the source for `update(attributes)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/582a90c09386839d7374fa1933ca4d805e1140a1/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L225) and you will see `assign_attributes(attributes)` followed by `save` (and it's in `save` that validations happen before actually persisting/saving).

Comment: @Justin, not working for me in rails 3.2.22, when i tried to assign the params like `@obj.assign_attributes( params[:obj] )` my `@obj` become `nil`

Answer (score 4):

You can call the `valid?` method to run the validations.

This doesn't guarantee that a subsequent save will succeed if some of your validations depend on the state of other objects in the database. Te save could also fail for reasons unconnected to validations (eg a foreign key constraint)

I'm not sure why you'd want this pattern

Comment: I am saving few objects of different models. So i collect errors of validations of each model and then show it in one popup.

Answer (score 0):

The object won't be saved if the passed argument doesn't produce a valid object, so you can use your way just fine. You can see the errors (if any) using the `@obj.errors` array.

Answer (score 0):

[`update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) method validate object and return false if object is invalid. So, you can just write:

```
if @obj.update_attributes( params[:obj] )
  # That have been update
else
  # Ups, errors!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can define a method

```
def valid_with_new_params(hash)
   self.attributes = hash
   valid?
end
```

But that would be unnecessary because `@obj.update_attributes(params[:obj])` returns `true` if the obj was successfully updated and `false` otherwise. Note also that internally the `update_attributes` method runs all validations on the `@obj` so that you have `@obj.errors`  available if the update failed.

Comment: the `attributes=` method is deprecated in new versions of Rails

Answer (score 0):

To update the attributes without saving them

```
@obj.attributes = params[:obj]   0r
@obj.attributes = {:name => “Rob”}
```

To then check if the object is valid

```
@obj.valid?
```

To check if there is any error

```
@obj.errors
```